# Website not up in other countries

Tags: wordpress, website, uptime

I have a website in Canada and according to https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime tests, my website is offline in 7 major European check points. It is live in Canada and working fine but when I travel abroad it will not work. My wordpress website domain is www.premiumfire.com

I have another website with the same host created the same time that is working abroad fine. Any idea how I can fix this block? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and try to rewrite your question so that it matches the site quidelines. Include the following: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

uptrends.com indicates a "HTTP Protocol" error. Your website isn't strictly down but returning a "403 Forbidden" error.

You should check the webserver configuration for issues (perhaps you're blocking based on geoip country code or something similar?)

It appears to be specific to this hostname, as another website hosted on the same IP address (http://onguardsecurity.org/) has 100% availability